# how require so that all object[] have same keys in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have next functions for convert array of objects to csv, objects need same keys, for it I write generic what verify it, but it work only if send object keys as separate array of strings

```
function toCSV<
  K extends string,
  T extends Record<K, string>
>
(fields: K[], data: T[]) {
  return json2csv.parse(data);
}

function toCSV2<
  K extends string,
  T extends Record<K, string>
  >
(data: T[]) {
  return json2csv.parse(data);
}


toCSV(['a'], [{a: '1'}, { b: '2'}]); // show error
toCSV2([{a: '1'}, { b: '2'}]); // not show error
```

I want use toCSV2 but it not find type errors

Comment: From what I interpret in your question, you are saying that `toCSV` doesn't show an error, but `toCSV2` does show an error. However, in the supplied code, you have a comment that says the opposite. Can you please clarify?

Comment: truth in code, but I already find solution and add answer

Answer (score 0):

solution is easier than expected

```
function toCSV2<K extends string>(data: Record<K, string>[]) {
  return json2csv.parse(data);
}
toCSV2([{a: '1',}, { b: '2'}]); // show error
```